# RubyMotion - Duplicate symbols when linking?

Tags: ios, tesseract, rubymotion

I've added a 3rd party library (Tesseract) to a project. The library builds and runs with no errors when used in an XCode project. My RubyMotion project builds, but fails when linking:

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
vendor/Tesseract/build-iPhoneSimulator/libTesseract.a(svpaint.o)
./build/iPhoneSimulator-5.0-Development/objs/main.o
duplicate symbol _selCopy in:
vendor/Tesseract/build-iPhoneSimulator/libTesseract.a(sel1.o)
/Library/RubyMotion/data/5.0/iPhoneSimulator/libmacruby-static.a(id.o)
duplicate symbol _selWrite in:
vendor/Tesseract/build-iPhoneSimulator/libTesseract.a(sel1.o)
/Library/RubyMotion/data/5.0/iPhoneSimulator/libmacruby-static.a(id.o)
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
```

I've tried adding Tesseract two different ways, as a `:static` library and as an `:xcode` project. Same error both ways.

Given that I'm able to build and run a normal Xcode project which uses this library, I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with RubyMotion.

Comment: I am running into this exact problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Ian - Good news: yes, I solved this issue. Just posted an answer to the question.

Bad news: I'm stuck on a new error. The project builds successfully, but when I call into Tesseract (even with a simple test like `Tesseract.alloc.initWithDataPath`), it fails with an undefined symbol error for _tesseract.

RubyMotion support has been unresponsive, PLEASE let me know if you figure this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by building Tesseract with the `--disable-graphics` option for configure, as mentioned in their [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: Have you had much luck with the quality of this library?